# How to save data after fetch from redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a bug when I code my project. The bug is when I get data from redux-saga, I have a list job, and when I click on any job, it will be navigated to the Detail job screen, and on this screen, I had run useEffect to get detail job from redux-saga. And, when I go back to the Home screen, the job list was cleared.
[List job get from redux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lseg6.png)

[detail job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quyDf.png)

[list is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIrSG.png)

[Home screen's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO3wW.png)

[Detail screen's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MV2w.png)

Comment: Please post the code, not just the code images. It will help to evaluate.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.